# How to use command "publish-local" of SBT to maven repo?

Tags: maven, sbt, scala-breeze

The first project is an SBT project. Command "publish-local" only publishes jars to the local .ivy repository. But, another project is a maven project. I want SBT "publish-local" to maven repository. So another project can reference them from the .m2 repository. I don't know what to do?

Here is `build.sbt`:

```scala
    organization := "org.scalanlp"

    name := "breeze-parent"

    lazy val root = project.in( file(".") )
    .aggregate(math, natives, viz, macros).dependsOn(math, viz)

    lazy val macros = project.in( file("macros"))

    lazy val math = project.in( file("math")).dependsOn(macros)

    lazy val natives = project.in(file("natives")).dependsOn(math)

    lazy val viz = project.in( file("viz")).dependsOn(math)

    lazy val benchmark = project.in(file("benchmark")).dependsOn(math, natives)

    scalaVersion := Common.scalaVersion

    crossScalaVersions  := Common.crossScalaVersions

    addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" %% "paradise" % "2.0.1" cross CrossVersion.full)

    publishMavenStyle := true

    publishTo <<= version { (v: String) =>
      val nexus = "https://oss.sonatype.org/"
      if (v.trim.endsWith("SNAPSHOT"))
        Some("snapshots" at nexus + "content/repositories/snapshots")
      else
        Some("releases"  at nexus + "service/local/staging/deploy/maven2")
    }

    publishArtifact in Test := false

    pomIncludeRepository := { _ => false }

    pomExtra := (
      <url>http://scalanlp.org/</url>
      <licenses>
        <license>
          <name>Apache 2</name>
          <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
          <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
      </licenses>
      <scm>
        <url>git@github.com:scalanlp/breeze.git</url>
        <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:scalanlp/breeze.git</connection>
      </scm>
      <developers>
        <developer>
          <id>dlwh</id>
          <name>David Hall</name>
          <url>http://www.dlwh.org/</url>
        </developer>
      </developers>)
```

Comment: Could you check the 'publishM2' task? Its documentation says 'Publishes artifacts to the local Maven repository'

Comment: @AjayPadala Yep I think that's the answer. Are there cases in which it's better to answer in a comment? I'm still learning StackOverflow etiquette, but I'm pretty sure it's unkind to respond with the same answer after you've provided it in comment form.

Comment: I'm not sure either, pretty new to this myself. changed to an answer :)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Please use the `publishM2` task. Its documentation says "Publishes artifacts to the local Maven repository".

```
sbt publishM2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the docs that says `publishM2` as per Ajay answer:

- https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Publishing.html

> The publishLocal task will publish to the “local” Ivy repository ...
>
> Similar to publishLocal, publishM2 task will publish the user’s Maven
> local repository. This is at the location specified by
> $HOME/.m2/settings.xml or at $HOME/.m2/repository/ by default. Another
> build would require Resolver.mavenLocal to resolve out of it:
>
> resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal